# Converting .xls to .xlsx using excelcnv.exe or ofc.exe in C#

Tags: c#, .net, excel, iis

I am trying to run a 'EXE' using c# code to convert .xls to .xlsx. It is running successfully and working as expected if I run using a console application or cmd.

But when I am running it in server side (code hosted in IIS i.e code running using w3wp.exe worker process) it unable to convert files to .xlsx

First, I used **Excelcnv.exe** to convert

```
if (System.IO.File.Exists(pstrIPDTemplatePath))
            {
                string pstrOpenXMLIPDTemplatePath = pstrIPDTemplatePath.Replace(".xls", ".xlsx");
                string processArguments = "-oice \"" + pstrIPDTemplatePath + "\" \"" + pstrOpenXMLIPDTemplatePath + "\"";
                ProcessStartInfo Excelcnv = new ProcessStartInfo();
                Excelcnv.FileName = mstrExcelCnvExePath;
                Excelcnv.Arguments = processArguments;
                Process.Start(Excelcnv);
            }
```

It converted few files successfully but for few files it is creating excelcnv.exe*32 process in task manager, but it is not converting excel file. I even used event handlers for output, but the result is null. Process is going to indefinite state.

But if I am Running it through console application it converted the file successfully it also popped up a dialog after running it to convert multiple files that Excel did not launch correctly and asking whether to start in Safe Mode.

To avoid this safe mode issue, I tried to use **ofc.exe**

So, I used **ofc.exe** to convert as below:

```
Process prc = new Process();
prc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
prc.StartInfo.FileName = @"OFC.exe";
prc.StartInfo.Arguments = @"ofc.ini";
prc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
prc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
prc.Start();
```

Same case with this code. It is working successfully and converting as expected when running via console application.

It is unable to convert to .xlsx but creating the process in task manager and log file is empty when running using w3wp process hosted in IIS.

Even after giving IIS_IUSRS permission to 'EXE' location, it is not working but its working in console application.

Any ideas why this is happening, and how to get around it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add your w3wp running user to 'Administrator' group. It will work.

Otherwise use this which is mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49746655/5076486)